# Importing 24 word mnemonic to bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, seed, mnemonic-seed

How can I import my 24 word mnemonic seed into bitcoin-qt?
I think that I will have to convert it to some other format but I don't know how to do that nor what format to use. BIP 39 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Bitcoin Core does not currently allow the importing of seeds or mnemonics.

Comment: couldn't one use "https://iancoleman.io/bip39/", enter the 24 words, and at the very bottom get a list of priv & pub keys, that can be imported into bitcoin core (1 by 1) ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but that's not importing the mnemonic or seed directly into Core. You could still miss some private keys and if you continued to use the wallet that had the mnemonic, then you would likely miss later transactions too.

Comment: Electrum can do it. There's no Python script or something to convert it into a format Bitcoin Core can import?

Comment: @Geremia It is not a format or encoding issue. It is the fact that Bitcoin Core cannot handle the 512 bit BIP 32 seeds that BIP 39 mnemonics always produce.

Comment: any updates, Please add console option!

Comment: yes You Can`t, but you could create new wallet then export the private key